# Print arrays from the middle out

Tags: code-golf, array

This is a code-golf question.

Given integers s and n the task is to output all arrays of length n which take values from -s to s.  The only twist is that you must output them in the following order.

- The all zeros array of length n.
- All arrays of length n with elements from -1 to 1 excluding any array you have outputted before.
- All arrays of length n with elements from -2 to 2 excluding any array you have outputted before.
- And so on until you get to all arrays of length n with elements from -s to s excluding any array you have outputted before.

You should output one array per line. They can be space or comma separated.

Here is some non-complying python code that outputs the arrays/lists/tuples in the right order.

```
import itertools

s =  3
n = 2

oldsofar = set()
newsofar = set()
for i in xrange(s):
    for k in itertools.product(range(-i,i+1), repeat = n):
        newsofar.add(k)
    print newsofar - oldsofar
    oldsofar = newsofar.copy()
    print "***"
```

Extra glory (and an upvote from me) for answers  that perform no set subtraction or equivalent.

Comment: Can we write a function that prints the result?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I would prefer a complete program.  If this is deemed seriously controversial I will give in of course :)

Comment: Is there any required order within each of your bullet points?

Comment: @MartinBüttner No, not at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Jelly, 9 bytes

```
NRṗµAṀ€Ụị
```

No list subtraction was used in the making of this post. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=TlLhuZfCtUHhuYDigqzhu6Thu4s&input=&args=Mw+Mg)

#### How it works

```
NRṗµAṀ€Ụị  Main link. Arguments: s, n

N          Negate; yield -s.
 R         Range; yield [-s, ..., s].
  ṗ        Cartesian power; push all vectors of length n of those elements.
   µ       Begin a new, monadic link. Argument: L (list of vectors)
    A      Compute the absolute values of all vector components.
     Ṁ€    Get the maximum component of each vector.
       Ụ   Sort the indices of A according to the maximal absolute value of the
           corresponding vector's components.
        ị  Retrieve the vectors of A at those indices.
```

Comment: Now it's just getting silly!

Comment: "No lists were harmed in the making of this post"

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 18 bytes

```
_G2$:iZ^t!|X>4#SY)
```

First input is `s`, second is `n`

This works in [current version (15.0.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/15.0.0) of the language.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=X0cyJDppWl50IXxYPjQjU1kp&input=Mwoy)

#### Explanation

```
_      % take input s implicitly. Negate to obtain -s
G      % push input s again
2$:    % inclusive range from -s to s
i      % take input n
Z^     % Cartesian power. Gives 2D array, with each result on a row
t!     % duplicate and transpose
|      % absolute value
X>     % maximum of each column 
4#S    % sort and push the indices of the sorting
Y)     % apply as row indices into the 2D array. Display implicitly
```

Comment: 18 bytes is outrageous :)

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```
n#s=[c|b<-[0..s],c<-mapM id$[-b..b]<$[1..n],any((b==).abs)c]
```

Usage example: `2#2`-> `[[0,0],[-1,-1],[-1,0],[-1,1],[0,-1],[0,1],[1,-1],[1,0],[1,1],[-2,-2],[-2,-1],[-2,0],[-2,1],[-2,2],[-1,-2],[-1,2],[0,-2],[0,2],[1,-2],[1,2],[2,-2],[2,-1],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]`.

How it works:

```
   b<-[0..s]                           -- loop b through 0 .. s
        c<-mapM id$[-b..b]<$[1..n]     -- loop c through all lists of length n
                                       -- made out of the numbers -b .. b
                                       -- ("[-b..b]<$[1..n]" is "replicate n [-b..b]";
                                       --  "mapM id" is "sequence")
[c|                 ,any((b==).abs)c]  -- keep c if it contains b or -b
```

Edit: @xnor pointed out that `mapM id` is `sequence`.

Comment: `mapM id` is shorter than `sequence`.

Comment: @xnor: True. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 83 bytes

```
Print/@Select[Range[-#,b=#]~Tuples~a,Abs@#~MemberQ~b&]&/@Range[0,a=Input[];Input[]]
```

To use, put in a script and input `n` then `s` on separate lines. Prints each array as a curly-bracketed, comma-delimited list (e.g., `{-1, 0, 1}`). It works by taking every list of length `n` with numbers between `[-cur..cur]`, and and printing those which include either `-cur` or `cur`. It then repeats this for all `cur` in `[0..s]`. <sup>(This post contains 19 ` characters!)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (SpiderMonkey 30+), 134 bytes

```
(s,n)=>n?[for(a of f(s,n-1))for(i of Array(s*2+1).keys())[i-n,...a]].sort((a,b)=>g(a)-g(b),g=a=>Math.max(...a,-Math.min(...a))):[[]]
```

Uses the cartesian-power-and-sort approach, which I thought of separately, but I was recompiling SpiderMonkey at the time so I unable to answer this before @Dennis.